# Выберите правильно оформленные комментарии

Tags: html, валидация, html-validation

Еще один вопрос из теста с сайта mail.ru
Хочу заметить, что тест на знание, именно, HTML5
90% вопросов из этого теста на тему валидации и семантики, но иногда встречаются вопросики про скрипты или события
Тест я сдал, с ошибками, не с первого раза, но сдал
Теперь хочу разобраться с одной из ошибок
Вопрос на картинке:
[image: Вопрос из теста]

Этот вопрос попадался мне два раза, два раза ответил не верно. И от этого мне больно. Вроде это моя основная технология, работаю с ней лет так дцать, а комментарии делать не умею. Рукалицо

В первый раз я решил, что вопрос конкретный и понимать его следует прямо, как есть. Ответил: 1,2,3,5,6. Не верно
Во второй раз я выбрал только HTML комментарии: 1,5,6. Кстати, я проверил в валидаторе - это корректные комментарии, но... снова не верно

Так как верно-то?

Comment: `<!-- текст -->` html комментарий для одной или нескольких строк